# Detectron2 installation in Windows Causes Me a big error

Tags: python, conda

I'm Jitesh, a Python programmer trying to install detectron2 on Windows. While installing detectron2, I ran an error.

```
This is the segement of the code:
 Emitting ninja build file C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build.ninja...
  Compiling objects...
  Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
  1.10.0.git.kitware.jobserver-1
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\torch\lib /LIBPATH:c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" c10.lib torch.lib torch_cpu.lib torch_python.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__C C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\detectron2\layers\csrc\vision.obj C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\detectron2\layers\csrc\box_iou_rotated\box_iou_rotated_cpu.obj C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\detectron2\layers\csrc\cocoeval\cocoeval.obj C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\detectron2\layers\csrc\nms_rotated\nms_rotated_cpu.obj C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\detectron2\layers\csrc\ROIAlign\ROIAlign_cpu.obj C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\detectron2\layers\csrc\ROIAlignRotated\ROIAlignRotated_cpu.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\detectron2\_C.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\detectron2\layers\csrc\_C.cp38-win_amd64.lib
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-9z8ky448\detectron2\layers\csrc\vision.obj'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
  Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 59, in closed
      return stream.closed
  ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for detectron2
```

Please help me

Comment: [Error](https://github.com/jitesh2910/socio-companion/blob/main/error.txt). Do check out this link to see the full error code

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/72784255/12635565

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Finally, I solved it buy:

1. Deleting build directory in Detectron2 (`rm -rf build/ **/*.so`)
2. cd to the Detectron2 and `pip install -e.`

It builds the wheel again.