# Unable to install detectron2 on Windows 10

Tags: pytorch, detectron

I am using a windows 10 machine with the following configuration
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650Ti
miniconda3
python 3.8
CUDA 11.1
PyTorch 1.8 downloaded directly & installed from PyTorch.org for CUDA-11.1
I have tried to install detectron2 based on the steps given in

https://dgmaxime.medium.com/how-to-easily-install-detectron2-on-windows-10-39186139101c

I have succesfully tested PyTorch installation however in the link given when I come to Step 5
that is

```
pip install -e .
```

My setup of detectron2 fails and gives me a huge list of errors that start with

Running setup.py develop for detectron2
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\torch\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\user\detectron2-windows\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\user\detectron2-windows\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
cwd: C:\Users\user\detectron2-windows
Complete output (3245 lines):
running develop
running egg_info
writing detectron2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to detectron2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to detectron2.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to detectron2.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

.... which goes on for almost hundreds of lines. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/72784255/12635565