# Can't build Detectron2 on Windows 10

Tags: pytorch, detectron

Although there's no official support for Detectron2 on Windows, there're many instructions available. I tried following these instruction, but ended up with the same error.

Here's my setup:

**OS**: Windows 10 Pro 19043.1466

**Microsoft Visual Studio**: 2019

**CUDA**: 11.3

[image]

Here's the installation algorithm I'm trying to follow (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70498119/1897063)

1. Set up environment variables for Microsoft Visual Studio by running `vcvars64.bat`:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat

[image]

2. Add new system path for `cl.exe` in my PATH variable:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64

3. Open Anaconda Promt with administrator privileges
4. Create new Conda environment with Python 3.7:

> conda create -n detectron_env python=3.7

5. Activate newly created environment detectron_env:

> conda activate detectron_env

6. Install cudatoolkit for CUDA 11.3

> conda install –c anaconda cudatoolkit=11.3

7. Install cudnn

> conda install -c anaconda cudnn

8. Install pywin32

> conda install -c anaconda pywin32

9. Install pytorch, torchvision and torchaudio for CUDA 11.3
   [image]

> conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c
> pytorch

10. Check whether GPU is enabled for Pytorch:

> python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())"

[image]

11. Install additional packages

> conda install -c anaconda cython
>
> pip install opencv-python
>
> pip install git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/fvcore
>
> pip install
> git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI
>
> pip install av
>
> conda install -c anaconda scipy
>
> conda install -c anaconda ninja

12. Go to the directory where I want to install detectron2

> e:
>
> cd e:/TRON

13. Git clone detectron2 repository

> git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git
> detectron_repo

14. Install dependencies

> pip install -q -e detectron_repo

And everything breaks here:

```
(detectron_env) e:\TRON>pip install -q -e detectron_repo
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'E:\\TRON\\detectron_repo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'E:\\TRON\\detectron_repo\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
         cwd: E:\TRON\detectron_repo\
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running develop
    running egg_info
    writing detectron2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to detectron2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to detectron2.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to detectron2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    adding license file 'LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 59, in closed
        return stream.closed
    ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'E:\\TRON\\detectron_repo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'E:\\TRON\\detectron_repo\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried to get past the problem by changing `build_ext` to `build_ext --inplace` in `setup.py` (line 208):

```
cmdclass={"build_ext --inplace": torch.utils.cpp_extension.BuildExtension}
```

Here's the result of running step 14 with these changes applied:

```
(detectron_env) e:\TRON>pip install -q -e detectron_repo
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'E:\\TRON\\detectron_repo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'E:\\TRON\\detectron_repo\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
         cwd: E:\TRON\detectron_repo\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running develop
    running egg_info
    writing detectron2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to detectron2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to detectron2.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to detectron2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    adding license file 'LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'detectron2._C' extension
    error: Don't know how to compile E:\TRON\detectron_repo\detectron2\layers\csrc\box_iou_rotated\box_iou_rotated_cuda.cu
    Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 59, in closed
        return stream.closed
    ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\detectron_env\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'E:\\TRON\\detectron_repo\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'E:\\TRON\\detectron_repo\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps Check the logs for full command output.
```

It says "Don't know how to compile E:\TRON\detectron_repo\detectron2\layers\csrc\box_iou_rotated\box_iou_rotated_cuda.cu". What's the origin of the problem? Is it coming from Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/72784255/12635565

Comment: I got as far as you did, and then it broke on install.  This solved it for me: https://github.com/Ikomia-dev/detectron2/commit/cf546cfdae29b1f032f58a7d0340140443ee0603

Comment: @FDI no, I had to use Ubuntu instead.

Comment: For me it was that I had previously had CUDA computing toolkit on my system (11.2). Although I uninstalled it, the "Nvidia GPU Computing Toolkit" directory still existed under C:/Program Files. That made the build choose the system installation (11.2) instead of the correct 11.3 version installed with conda which caused the error. I deleted the "Nvidia GPU Computing Toolkit" directory and the error is gone