# How to create yml file with the specific code in it

Tags: python, conda

I want to create environment.yml file with the specific code from the first answer here: [Install Detectron2 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631933/install-detectron2-on-windows-10). But I don't get how actually I can do this. Please, any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like this is asking "How do I use a text editor?". Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation, create a `environment.yaml` file manually then insert you code, after that run the following command:

```
conda env create --file=environment.yaml
```

or

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

That would be the manual method, if you want to do it by command you can follow their documentation here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

Comment: I get an error: EnvironmentFileNotFound: 'C:\Users\friske\environment.yaml' file not found

Comment: But how do I actually create this file manually? I don't get also from conda documentation: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually