# How to install Detectron2

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, ocr, python-3.10

I am installing layout-parser and following this [link](https://layout-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html). Did not face any issues with the following packages.

```
pip install layoutparser    
pip install "layoutparser[effdet]"    
pip install layoutparser torchvision     
pip install "layoutparser[paddledetection]"    
pip install "layoutparser[ocr]"
```

But I am not able to install detectron2

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.5#egg=detectron2"
```

while installing this package I am getting this error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement detectron2 (unavailable) (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for detectron2 (unavailable)

I followed the same installation guide in Google collab and it worked but not able to install them in my Azure workspace.

Answer (score 5):

Check your python version. If you have Python version as 3.10 or higher you will face this issue. This is because detectron2 library has only wheels for <= Python 3.9.

Comment: The list of whl files and supported Python versions can be found [here](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html#install-pre-built-detectron2-linux-only) . E.g. for cuda 11.3 whl the link for [whl is this](https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu113/torch1.10/index.html) and supported versions are:
detectron2-0.6+cu113-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
detectron2-0.6+cu113-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
detectron2-0.6+cu113-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
detectron2-0.6+cu113-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal or command prompt.
Create a new environment called detectron2-env with the following command:

```
conda create --name detectron2-env python==3.9 -y
```

Activate the environment with the following command:

## Linux

```
conda activate detectron2-env
```

## Windows

```
activate detectron2-env
```

Install the dependencies with the following commands:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git
python -m pip install -e detectron2
```

For more help, please refer to the following documentation:

https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In colab, I use:

```
!pip install -q torch torchvision --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
!pip install -q 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git'
```

For windows, there is the great conda [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631933/install-detectron2-on-windows-10).